# Is it possible to modify Dashboard Designer deployment process?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, dashboard, performancepoint, dashboard-designer

I want to know if it is possible to do some custom code that would be executed when you click on "Deploy to SharePoint" on a dashboard element in Dashboard Designer.

Basically, what I would like to do is set some of the WebPart properties while I generate my dashboard. I'd like to see the WebPart navigation URL with one of the dashboard custom property I created.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to post an update, I was never able to achieve that. I did not put much further investigation in that since my client dropped performance point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything I could possibly think of, and my answer to that question is NO. You can't.